# How to update maven in ubuntu using command

Tags: maven, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I have Maven 3.0.3 installed. Now I want to update it to Maven 3.0.4 due some surefire plug-in issue. But I do not know how to do that from command line.

Does anyone having any idea?

Comment: AFAIK, it's just a matter of replacing your old Maven directory with new one downloaded from Maven's website. No?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply define the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) versions in pluginManagement section of your pom or better in a company pom.

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.12.3</version>
       </plugin>
       ...
    </plugin>
  </pluginManagmenet>
</build>
```

If you don't have already a company wide pom your build is not reproducible which means if you change your maven version your build will use different plugin version which is true for all plugins. Furthermore it's best practice to define the versions of plugins in a build. There is no need to update Maven itself. You can if you running into Maven issues but not for plugins.

Answer (score 19):

I have just done it....
I exchange Maven 3.0.3 for now Maven 3.2.1
I did this steps:

1. Remove old maven version:

   ```
   > sudo apt-get remove maven
   > sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Installation new version:
      Now I have improved my knowledge about linux I prefer to install the
      software by hand ;)
      So... I followed the Apache Installation Instruction on 
      http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and then I have added this rows
      in the file .baschrc:

   ```
        export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1
        export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
        export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
        export PATH=$PATH:$M2
   ```

I hope would be useful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to do it from the command line? Even if your distribution doesn't provide the update you need, installing Maven only requires downloading an archive, uncompressing it in a suitable folder and setting a couple of environment variables.

You can find the official installation instructions [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.html#Installation)

Answer (score 0):

you are right effectiveness you could have both or more and switch setting the M2_HOME in the .profile, but I don't need the old one and I think is clearer have just one.
Anyway thanks maybe someone need more then one version and could find this post interesting.